# How to place a ListPlot in a Texture without losing resolution?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, textures

I have a code that produces the left plot (vectorised image), and makes into a `Texture` in order to have it under a `ListPlot3D` (right):

[image]

**Problem**: the left image loses resolution when made into a `Texture`.

Here is a MWE:

```
a = ListPlot[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 13, 1}, {j, 1, 13, 1}], 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Opacity[0.5], Darker[Blue], PointSize[0.025]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
maxg = 6; level = 0
Graphics3D[{Texture[a], 
  EdgeForm[], {Polygon[{{-maxg, -maxg, level}, {maxg, -maxg, 
      level}, {maxg, maxg, level}, {-maxg, maxg, level}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

How can I make sure that the plot in my `Graphics3D` is still vectorised?

Comment: Does it help `Texture[Rasterize[a, ImageResolution -> 360]]`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to form a Texture.  Check:  `SliceDensityPlot3D`

Comment: But I have discrete data, can I still use `SliceDensityPlot3D`?

Comment: @Kuba yes it does make it better, thanks. If I try too high resolution it runs into memory error. I guess I would just like to make the bottom contour plot a vectorised image since it's vectorised to start with...